# javascript aligning on a single line

Tags: asp.net

I want the text box and the Apply button to be on the straight line. What am I doing wrong?

```
<tr align = "center" valign ="bottom"> 
  <td align="left" style="padding-top: 15px; height: 30px;">
      Promo Code</br><asp:TextBox ID="txtCouponCode" runat="server" MaxLength="10" TabIndex="5" Width="130px" />
 <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" ImageUrl="../images/apply-blue.gif" runat="server" 
   OnClick="imgApply_Click" ValidationGroup="0"/>
```

Comment: next time hightlight your code and then click the little 010101 icon so you get code formatting :)

Comment: Do you mean that when it renders in the browser they are not on the same line?

Comment: can you show the HTML that is rendered?

Comment: also: wheres the JavaScript you mention in your title?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aside from the minor issue with your malformed BREAK tag:

`</br>` Should be `<br />`

... and assuming that you are in fact closing out your table row and table data tags. Then your snippet:

```
<tr align = "center" valign ="bottom"> 
  <td align="left" style="padding-top: 15px; height: 30px;">
      Promo Code<br /><asp:TextBox ID="txtCouponCode" runat="server" MaxLength="10" TabIndex="5" Width="130px" />
 <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" ImageUrl="../images/apply-blue.gif" runat="server" 
   OnClick="imgApply_Click" ValidationGroup="0"/>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Should produce roughly the following HTML:

```
<tr align="center" valign="bottom"> 
    <td align="left" style="padding-top: 15px; height: 30px;"> 
        Promo Code<br /><input name="txtCouponCode" type="text" maxlength="10" id="txtCouponCode" tabindex="5" style="width:130px;" /> 
        <input type="image" name="ImageButton1" id="ImageButton1" src="../images/apply-blue.gif" /> 
    </td> 
</tr>
```

Which should render exactly the way you want. So... could you provide some more context?

Comment: Hey, I have used Imagealign = bottom, it worked.. Thanks so much guys!!

Answer (score 0):

How does it appear now, one on top of the other?

Try adding the `NOWRAP` attribute to your table i.e. `<td align=left nowrap>`

Beware the incoming flood of posts berating you for using tables for layout purposes!